# Laravel Send mail in side proxy network

Tags: php, laravel, proxy, smtp

I am just implementing like password reset system.
The Sending Mail system is working in home without the proxy setup.
But inside the proxy setup system is not working(both are in localhost).
when i upload to the server its working.
Then why in the localhost under the proxy setup network system is not working???

[It shows the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xQcj.png)

> Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421
>   Cannot connect to SMTP server 74.125.200.109 (74.125.200.109:587),
>   connect error 10060 "

This is my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=test@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

my config/mail.php

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'MYNAME'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

Since i am new to `laravel` ,
Is there any setting need to do OR Should i want to configure the proxy name and port number(how to configure the proxy setup in laravel) ...
please help me .. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want use your gmail account in another apps, You should enable [Let less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) option

Also you can define another key for your account ( different that you account password ). You should have a key like this when you are using 2FA

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache` after any changes in `.env` file

Comment: yes i enable the less secure apps option, but the system is working in my home laptop network is normal, when i change the proxy setup network its not working.  Also when i upload to the hosts its working. i am asking why inside the proxy setup network it shows the error???

Comment: I have no idea about that, check web server logs or Laravel log for any information, maybe there is an privacy issue when using proxy ( because your IP will be changed ) @sripiranavanyoagarajah

Comment: Thank you for your help @Arash Hatami

Comment: @sripiranavanyoagarajah I have the same problem with proxy on send Email